# The usage of the phrase "every other"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, phrases

We know that "every other" means not each one in a series, but every two.

**For instance:**

> The conference used to be held every year, but now it takes place every other year.

But can we say for example:

> 1. The Olympic games take place **every other four years**.
> 2. That event takes place **every other several years**.

Dictionaries unfortunately, do not give me enough information on this phrase.

Comment: The Olympic games takes place every four years.

Comment: @WeatherVane Or "every fourth year" but your version is definitely the more common. "Every other four years" is wrong.

Comment: In the second case, "every few years".

Comment: *takes place* ?

Comment: +1 for TypelA and Weather Vane. But please let me know "why" it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you say 'every other biennial year'? Possibly, but it would be a very strange way of saying every 4 years.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is that *every other* refers to something that alternates - so *every other four years* would mean *every eighth year*. As @Smock has pointed out, it would be very a strange way of saying that (!) - so much so that most people would assume the speaker really meant *every four years*. I don't think it's ungrammatical per se though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not. Your construction is just about understandable, but you are mixing two different 'measures'.

"Every other [event]" always means "Every second [event]" so you cannot mix it with a specific number, though most native speakers would assume that the specific number was what was intended.